# finding interpolated values from cfit

Tags: matlab, interpolation, curve-fitting

I have fitted a curve on the basis of some data points that I have. After doing that I get a cfit object. If I plot cfit then I can see the curve. However, I need the interpolated data points from the cfit so that I can find the Harmonic Distortion of the signal. 
How do I get the interpolated data points?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `cfit` object, all you need to do is evaluate in the points you are interested in. Here is an example code based on the [Matlab Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/evaluate-a-curve-fit.html):

```
load census
curvefit = fit(cdate,pop,'poly3','normalize','on');
plot(curvefit,cdate,pop);
```

[image]

**Evaluate the Fit Values at Many Points**

```
xi = (2000:10:2050).';
y = curvefit(xi)

y = 

  276.9632
  305.4420
  335.5066
  367.1802
  400.4859
  435.4468
```

You can now use `xi` and `y` as your interpolated data points.

Comment: I tried this method but all I am getting is a straight line. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to share your code to get help. There is no way to know what's wrong like this. Update the question to include what you are doing.